# converting serial read from python2 to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and am trying to convert a very old utility I have from python2 to python3. I've searched and searched for answers, but I've yet to find an explanation for the behavior that I'm seeing or how to fix it...

I'm grabbing data from a USB(serial) device like this:

```
class TED(object):
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.port = serial.Serial(device, 19200, timeout=0)
        self.escape_flag = False

    def poll(self):
        self.port.write(b'\xAA')
        return self.decode(self.port.read(4096))

    def decode(self, raw):
        print("raw=%s" % raw)
```

elsewhere I do stuff with the raw result, but for now, I'm just printing it to the screen and the results between python2 and python3 are drastically different.

In python2, I get the expected result, which is basically a bunch of control characters and other crap that makes the terminal screen all screwy. This indicates that the data contained within **raw** is in-fact the raw results from the serial port and an strace reveals it as such:

```
read(3, "\0\34S\0\0\356\6#\4M\320:\3\311d\261s\7\330\5e\261j\7\321\5f\261L\n\31\10"..., 4096) = 361
write(1, "raw=\0\34S\0\0\356\6#\4M\320:\3\311d\261s\7\330\5e\261j\7\321\5f\261"..., 335
```

In python3, the value of **raw** appears to be a string that just shows the hex values of the actual data, and it prints to the screen in plain text. Such as:

```
raw=b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x04\n\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x1d\x01\x00\x00^\x01\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdf\x02\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x01\x15\xe8\x03\x01\xe4\x90\x00TED \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f'\x0f'\x0f'\x0f'\xe8\x03\xdc\x05\xc1\x04\xc9\x00\xe7\x04\xa9\x00j\x04c\xaf\x05V\xec\x03O\x00d\t\xb5\x00\x86P\x12\x00P'\x17\x00AS\x00\x00\xd5\xbc$\x04\xb0*<\x03\xc9d\xb1s\x07\xd8\x05e\xb1j\x07\xd1\x05f\xb1L\n\x19\x08g\xb1]\n'\x08h\xb1d\x0b\xf6\x08i\xb16\n\x08\x08j\xb1I\x08\x81\x06k\xb1Q\x08\x88\x06\\\xb1\xad\x08\xd1\x06a\xb1_\x0b\xf3\x08b\xb1\x8b\x0b\x16\tc\xb1\x0c\x08Q\x06\xe4\x00\x12\x00\xde\x04\x89\x03c\nO\r\x0c|\xea\x00\x00\xbe?\x01\x00^\xd6l\x00\x88\x07m\x00\x00\x03\x10\x03"
```

An strace on python3 shows the difference between the input and the output:

```
read(3, "\20\4\n\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\0\35\1\0\0^\1\377\377\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 282
write(1, "raw=b\"\\x10\\x04\\n\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00"..., 962raw=b"\x10\x04\n\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x1d\x01\x00\x00^\x01\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdf\x02\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x01\x15\xe8\x03\x01\xe4\x90\x00TED \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f'\x0f'\x0f'\x0f'\xe8\x03\xdc\x05\xc1\x04\xc9\x00\xe7\x04\xa9\x00j\x04c\xaf\x05V\xec\x03O\x00d\t\xb5\x00\x9aW\x12\x00C0\x17\x00BS\x00\x00\xc8\xc5$\x04\xc41<\x03\xc9d\xb1s\x07\xd8\x05e\xb1j\x07\xd1\x05f\xb1L\n\x19\x08g\xb1]\n'\x08h\xb1d\x0b\xf6\x08i\xb16\n\x08\x08j\xb1I\x08\x81\x06k\xb1Q\x08\x88\x06\\\xb1\xad\x08\xd1\x06a\xb1_\x0b\xf3\x08b\xb1\x8b\x0b\x16\tc\xb1\x0c\x08Q\x06\xe4\x00\x12\x00\xde\x04\x89\x03c\nN\r\x0c\xbf\xe9\x00\x00r?\x01\x00\x0e\xd8l\x002\x00m\x00\x00\x03\x10\x03"
```

The result of all of this is that the remainder of the program is expecting raw data, not the converted string and it breaks as a result.

How do I get python3's read() to return the data in an un-manipulated form?

PS - Note that in the examples above, the actual data was different because the samples were taken at different times. The issue here is that the data is being manipulated in python3 so the write doesn't reflect the read.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: _the remainder of the program is expecting raw data_ That may be the problem. In python 2, string and raw data were both held in `str`. In python3, `str` is unicode enabled - its typically a wide character representation of unicode code points. `bytes` is for raw data. That's what the `b'whatever'` is - the raw bytes. If the rest of your program wants raw bytes... it should change to use `bytes` instead of `str`.

Comment: FYI, your `poll()` method returns `None`, since it returns the "value" from your `decode()` method--which doesn't return a value.

Comment: What is `TED.decode` supposed to do? Is there some sort of known encoding of the usb data? Or is it just adding `raw=`? It could just be `return b"raw=" + raw` to keep the `bytes` object. If you want your screen to go crazy, you would `sys.stdout.buffer.write(ted.poll())`.

Comment: TED.decode uses a mapping of the raw USB data response and breaks it into usable components later in the program.  The original program did a "for byte in raw" to extract those components.  I've tried changing it to "for bytes in raw", but since the values in raw no longer match, it fails subsequent tests.  I think I just need a  way to store the data exactly as read into raw.  I don't know how to take the converted raw in python3 and make it look like the read, as reflected in the strace.  Is there a way to change "return self.decode(self.port.read(4096))" to preserve the raw data format?